# Should I do many sql queries or one large query and do the processing on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

The situation is as follows: I have a large-ish dataset with a couple thousand entries that I populate from an Excel file. For each entry I have to match it to another field on a certain table in the database (this table contains only a couple hundred entries).

What's the best way to go about doing it? I can make a query for each entry in the dataset but this seems fairly wasteful; on the other hand I can just select the fields I need from all the entries in the table, put them on a Dictionary or some other data structure and match them on IIS, thus making effectively only one query but doing all the processing on the webserver.

Dataset : ~1000 to ~3000 entries

Table in the DB: ~300 entries

Using asp.net on IIS but the database is a MS access file.

Is either of these better the other? Is there a third, better way I haven't thought of?

Comment: Do the processing in the database.  The operation you want is a `join`, and databases are optimized for this type of data processing.

Comment: The problem is that my dataset isn't in the database, should I create a temporary table in the DB with it and join them from there?

Comment: This is very much dependent on the size of your datasets, as Gordon has said, SQL is optimised for join operations, and this would be the fastest way. Based on the size you have suggested however, if you have to create and populate a temporary table in access to do the join, then return the records to the server, then get rid of the temporary table, I'd have thought it would be quicker filling, and looping a dataset of a couple of thousand records, and filling, and looking up to a small dictionary of a couple of hundred records.

Comment: As stated, the database would process better, however, my guess is that the process of importing the data to the database would negate most of the gain. Remember that a dataset can contain multiple tables and you can create relationships between those tables. I haven't done much in that area, but would think you can leverage a relationship somehow. Bottom line, probably the only way to know for sure is to try both methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases are designed to do many things that are useful for data processing. A lot of benefits for transactional processing are contained in the acronym ACID -- atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability. In other words, databases behave the way you would expect when you store something in them. The data is there, relationships are enforced, it will be there tomorrow.

The features that you want are on the querying side. Databases in general (although perhaps not MS Access in particular) allow a relatively standard interface to powerful processing. Database engines know how to optimize queries. Database engines know how to manage memory. Database engines know how to manager hierarchical memory, with disk, RAM, and cache. Databases know how to take advantage of indexes, row partitions, and other optimizations (you can get this functionality by using a free version of a more advanced database, such as SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, or even MySQL).

You are talking about thousands of rows of data. Databases can easily work with millions of rows. You are talking about two tables.  Databases can easily manage many more tables and queries using a dozen.

So, no, you should not load your data into in-memory structures on the application side. You should do the processing in the database and bring back the results you want. Then, you can format the results on the application side, to take advantage of what applications do best:  interface to the user.